# How is the content-type for an <input type='file'> set?

Tags: http, forms, http-post

How does the browser determine what to set for the `content-type` for an `<input type='file'>`?

Is it based on the file name extension or does the browser scan the file contents to decide?

If it is based on the file name extension, what content-type value is used for a .csv file? How about file systems that do not use file name extensions?

Is the `content-type` value trustworthy at all?

Answer (score 0):

The content type is [set by the mime type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)) for the file when it is downloaded.

[The type attribute.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#attr-input-type)

Comment: Thanks. The first linked page is pretty informative. Is there a way to indicate filenames without extensions are permitted? I tried a period with nothing but such files are not listed in Chrome.

Comment: @OldGeezer File extensions mean nothing. It's the mime-type that determines how the browser handles it.